# How to skip other libs log to my log4j logger

Tags: java, log4j

I have small project that logs to log4j. Bellow is configuration:

```
log4j.debug=true
log4j.rootLogger=ALL,console


log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%-10t] %-5p %30c %60l  -  %m%n
```

I have added web server client to my project and libraries related to RPC started to log to my apender. Something like:

```
2015-09-03 15:10:59,857 [main      ] DEBUG  org.apache.axis.utils.NSStack          org.apache.axis.utils.NSStack.push(NSStack.java:85)  -  NSPush (32)
2015-09-03 15:10:59,857 [main      ] DEBUG  org.apache.axis.utils.NSStack          org.apache.axis.utils.NSStack.push(NSStack.java:85)  -  NSPush (32)
2015-09-03 15:10:59,858 [main      ] DEBUG org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle.handleGetObject(ProjectResourceBundle.java:72)  -  org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(register00)
2015-09-03 15:10:59,858 [main      ] DEBUG org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.registerPrefixForURI(SerializationContext.java:472)  -  register 'soapenv' - 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
2015-09-03 15:10:59,858 [main      ] DEBUG org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle.handleGetObject(ProjectResourceBundle.java:72)  -  org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(register00)
2015-09-03 15:10:59,858 [main      ] DEBUG org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.registerPrefixForURI(SerializationContext.java:472)  -  register 'xsd' - 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
```

How to make just my project log to my appender?

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the package in your log4j.properties. 
For example:

```
log4j.category.org.apache.axis=OFF
```

To exclude it completely. Or you can add a new appender and configure the package to the new appender, e.g.:

```
...
log4j.appender.NEW_APPENDER=...
...
log4j.category.org.apache.axis=INFO, NEW_APPENDER
```

Note that you can replace INFO with other level as you see fit.

Comment: NONE - did not helped. INFO - solved problem. Why NONE not working? How to skip info at all?

Comment: My bad, try OFF instead of NONE. I've also updated my answer.